# How to ignore invalid data from missing battery?

Tags: android, adb, energy

I made a battery bypass to a LG G4 mobile phone, to measure the direct energy consumption with a power monitor. However, 70-80 seconds into the OS boot-up, the system shuts-down with a message 'Invalid battery'.

I've tried several solutions, such as: setting a precise output voltage as measured on the battery; cleaning the 4 battery pins; tighter pin connection, but no luck.

The only hope I could find is within the android [docs](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/power/component) - Power/Component Power section:

> Fake batteries can provide signals on thermistor or fuel gauge pins that mimic temperature and state of charge readings for a normal system, and may also provide convenient leads for connecting to external power supplies. Alternatively, **you can modify the system to ignore the invalid data from the missing battery.**

And here is my question: How do I modify the system to ignore the invalid data from the missing battery?

There isn't a reference to any article or clear explanation on how to do this. Could anyone point me in the right direction, please? Am I missing something really straightforward?

Comment: I'd say "modify the system" means to download AOSP and build your own Android version that ignores that data...? But eventually, some forum like XDA-Developers is the better place to ask tinkering questions like this :)

Comment: Thanks @ThomasKeller. I have searched XDA developers forum and posted the question there too. If I find a solution (hopefully without rebuilding the OS), I'll post it back here.